# Spring binding PUT request params to an object

Tags: java, spring, multipart

I have an endpoint for updating some Order details. This endpoint receives a DTO with updates.

```
@PutMapping
public void updateOrder(OrderUpdateDTO updates)
```

The problem is when I use @PostMapping everything works fine and my request successfully binds to an object. But when I use @PutMapping all my fields are nulls. When I looked into request object itself - it doesn't have any parameters at all.

Possible solution could be to mark a method argument with @RequestBody but the issue is that one of the fields in `updates` is a file so I submit the whole form as a FormData object (which I cannot access with @RequestBody).

I couldn't find any mentions in Spring docs about the fact why POST automatically binds requests to classes and PUT does not.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How this Spring magic works (and why it works differently for POST and PUT)? (Or some links to any sources);
2. How can I combine Spring @PutMapping with multipart request to upload a file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use separate `Multipartfile` from `RequestBody` and use `RequestParam` ?

```
@PutMapping
public Foo updateOrder(
    @RequestPart UpdateOrderDto updates,
    @RequestPart MultipartFile file)
```

In the above case, you need to put 2 fields into form, `updates` and `file`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just tried it. It doesn't work. But even if it did it is not exactly what I need since UpdateOrderDto may contain multiple fileds like this (each would contain a List of files) and I don't want to separate all of them into separate params because semantically it is incorrect since those fields are the part of updates.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add your post request? I doubt how do you make a POST request that includes a multipart file inside the request body. And what HTTP client you're using to make a request? Postman, curl or directly from your client application? Please provide examples of how do you send requests.

Comment: I use FormData to send files along with other fields.